# android animate right to left

Tags: android, android-animation

I am applying animation on popup, right to left.
I am using this piece of code, but even after some experiments, it always scale from left to right

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<scale
android:fromYScale="0"
android:toYScale="1"
android:startOffset="0"
android:duration="300"

android:fromXScale="0.5"
android:toXScale="1"
android:fillBefore="true" />
```

I have tried setting pivotX to 1 but still the result is always same.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `translate` instead of `scale` (or both) ?

```
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="100%p"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p"
    android:toYDelta="100%p" />
```

Comment: no I want to scale, is there any other way we can acheive desired result with translate?

Comment: For the pivot, you set it at relative or absolute ?

Comment: I am using it in xml, i read its a float value, by default is 0, but its not working with even 1 value

Comment: You can specify the pivot to be absolute or relative. You could give it a try to check if it works.

Comment: Try something like `ScaleAnimation stretch = new ScaleAnimation(0f, 1f, 0.5f, 0.5f, ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1.0f, ScaleAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0.5f);` (not sure of exact name of parameters)

Comment: I have to show animate at appearance and dissappearance of popup, so I am using xml for this purpose